# Find for each people_id corresponding role_id with maximum count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am trying to extract the below information using SQL.
Schema of the table is as below:

person_id, role_id, count

Eg table:

```
p1, r1, 5
p1, r2, 3
p2, r1, 8
p1, r3, 7
p2, r2, 3
p3, r1, 10
p3, r2, 15
```

I want to write query to extract for each people_id the role_id with the maximum count. How can I do it in MYSql or oracle DB

For the above table the output should be as below

```
p1, r3, 7
p2, r2, 8
p3, r2, 15
```

Explanation of the above output:

```
p1 has the maximum count as r3 i.e. 7  
p2 has maximum count as r2 i.e. 8  
p3 has maximum count as r2 i.e.15
```

I am not able to figure out the SQL to extract this data. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring that the column name is called count (better to use something that isn't likely to be a reserved word in any flavour of SQL):-

```
SELECT a.person_id, a.role_id, a.count
FROM table a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT person_id, MAX(count) AS MaxCount
    FROM table
    GROUP BY person_id
) Sub1
ON a.person_id = Sub1.person_id AND a.count = Sub1.MaxCount
```

Comment: "select d1.nam, d1.rol, max(d1.cnt) from table d1 as d1 group by d1.nam;"    
This is quite simple :)

Comment: It is also not going to consistently work ;) . The value of d1.rol will come from one of the rows but not necessarily the one that goes with the highest d1.cnt.

Comment: Are you sure about it? The query should select the tuple with maximum count for the same people_id. Isn't this how group by should work. I checked the results and it does match. Am I missing something here.  
The query I used is below   
"select d1.people_id, d1.role, max(d1.count) from table d1 group by d1.people_id;"  
I don't see why this should not work?

Comment: Very sure. Your query will get each name and the max cnt for each name. But the rol column is not an aggregate column nor a group by column. The value returned for each name will one one for that name but which one is undefined. Generally it is the first one that it finds when processing, but this is not certain and may also change in future or between storage engines. For example with your test data for person p1 it will return count 7 (as that is the max), but the role returned might be r1, r2 or r3.

Answer (score 0):

One way is an aggregation and join:

```
select t.person_id, t.role_id, t.count
from t join
     (select person_id, max(count) as count
      from t
      group by person_id
     ) tsum
     on tsum.person_id = t.person_id and
        tsum.count = t.count;
```

However, this has a problem when there are duplicates with the same maximum count.

If you want an arbitrary role, when there are duplicates, then you can aggregate the results form this query:

```
select t.person_id, max(t.role_id), t.count
from (select t.person_id, t.role_id, t.count
      from t join
           (select person_id, max(count) as count
            from t
            group by person_id
           ) tsum
           on tsum.person_id = t.person_id and
              tsum.count = t.count
     ) t
group by t.person_id, t.count
```

There are alternative methods, but this works in both databases.

Comment: This simple query also works. I just tried it. Thanks for the response  .    

Query below:  
    

    select d1.name, d1.role, max(d1.cnt) from table d1 as d1 group by d1.name;

Comment: Would the below query work  
  
select d1.people_id, d1.role, max(d1.count) from table d1 group by d1.people_id;

Comment: In your second query how can I break ties if the column is role_name (varchar) instead of role_id (integer) ?

Comment: @user2519648 . . . Same idea.  `min()` and `max()` work on character fields as well as numeric fields as well as dates.